# Get sheet name and cell reference from Excel cell reference

Tags: c#, string, excel, split

I need a smart way to split an Excel cell reference in order to get the sheet name and cell reference. Generally Excel reference can take the following form:

- =Sheet1!$A$1 ---> Sheet1, $A$1
- ='Sheet 1'!$A$1 ---> Sheet 1, $A$1
- ='!Sheet 1'!$A$1 ---> !Sheet 1, $A$1
- ='&Sheet1'!$A$1 ---> &Sheet1, $A$1
- ='$Sheet1$'!$A$1 ---> $Sheet1$, $A$1

Because Excel allows special characters and spaces in the sheet name, which makes extracting the sheet name and cell address difficult.

Is there a better way to do this? Regex? I have 0 exp.

Note: I get the cell reference via Named Range, as such I am stuck with what I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex can handle the job.

First, you need parse simple sheet name, like 'Sheet1'. This name starts with letter and contains any characters except '!'.

```
(\w[^!]*)
```

Second, you need parse complex sheet name, that enclosed in single quotes:

```
'([^']+)'
```

Third, you need union these two regexes:

```
(\w[^!]*)|'([^']+)'
```

Finally, write the code:

```
private static ExtractSheetName(string cell)
{
    var match = Regex.Match(cell, @"(\w[^!]*)|('[^']+)'");
    if (match.Success)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(match.Groups[1].Value))
            return match.Groups[1].Value;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(match.Groups[2].Value))
            return match.Groups[2].Values;

    }

    return null;
}

. . .
// Using:
var sheetName = ExptractSheetName(cell);
string cellRef;
if (sheetName == null)
    cellRef = cell;
else
    cellRef = cell.Substring(sheetName.Length + 1);
```

Comment: I tried this and called the method ExtractSheetName(cell), replacing the word cell with "'$Sheet1$'!A1". I am not sure what I am expecting, as it spit out the same input. Unless I am using it wrong, also I am expecting the cell reference. Does this give out the second half of the input?

Comment: Oh. I'm sorry, I have not checked the code. The `Regex.Match` method parameters must be reversed. I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`?Application.Evaluate("INDIRECT(""Sheet1!A1"")").Address(false, false)`

`?Application.Evaluate("INDIRECT(""Sheet1!A1"")").WorkSheet.Name`

Where `Application` is the instance of `Excel.Application`

Comment: As mentioned in my post, I am getting these reference via Named Range, so I am stuck with what I have. String manipulation is my best choice

Comment: Can you show some code to explain what you mean by "getting these reference via Named Range, so I am stuck with"?

Answer (score 0):

try this

app.config file:

```
 <appSettings>

<add key="connectionstrings" value="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\16-07-2014\BDLS_Backup\TVM - Employee List-New.xls;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;;IMEX=2'"/>
</appSettings>
```

Program.cs:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["connectionstrings"];
        OleDbConnection oledbConn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        oledbConn.Open();

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", oledbConn);

        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
        da.Fill(ds);
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{

                   string EmployeeCode = row["EmployeeCode"].ToString();
}
```

Where ["EmployeeCode"] is the column name in sheet1

Comment: I am not sure how this is relevant to my question.